# Is this correct usage of the word “slack”?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, idioms

“The charger cord is getting pulled. Could you give it slack?”

What I want to convey here is, pull the cord in the other direction (to which it is being pulled right now) so that it becomes ‘loose’ and there is no more strain on it.
Is it idiomatic to say it the way I did?

...

(More detail, if needed: I have an extension board which I keep on the floor, by my bed. I usually work on my laptop in bed, and when I plug the laptop charger into the extension board, most of the charger (including the heavy adapter) either trails on the floor or down the side of my bed. This causes the “pulling” of the cord/cable close to where it connects into my laptop. The charger port also happens to face away from the side with the extension board.
So when this happens, I have to pull more of the cord towards the laptop so there is no more strain on the cord and it won’t get damaged.)

Comment: The concept of "slack" as a noun is perfectly acceptable but I would always say "give it _some_ slack" or "give it _a bit_ of slack". An alternative is to say "slacken it off", 'slacken' being a verb. Slacken can also be used of clothing, wrapping, and anything fastened with a screw thread including jar caps and bottle tops as well as bolts and screws.

Comment: If things are pulled in opposite directions at once, they become *taut*, the opposite of *slack*. The last thing you want to do to give yourself more length is pull the cord in the other direction. (That just reduces the length already gained.) The only way giving slack makes sense if if you pull the other end of the cord in the *same* direction as the part that doesn't have enough length—which only works if it's hung up on something and there is actually more length that can be provided.